# Is there a way to retrieve the publication list description?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

To retrieve the publication list name we using the %%_listname%%, but how to retrieve the description? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

The list description is not available via a personalization string, like the name is.

In order to get the description, you would need to use the SOAP API aimed at the [List Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/list.htm).  The property you are looking for is called 'Description'.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also use Server Side Javascript (SSJS) to find more details about any list within the Business Unit. You can run this script within an a CloudPage/Microsite.

Here is the sample code:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
  var listArray = List.Retrieve({Property:"ListName",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"SampleName"});
  var Stringlists = Stringify(listArray);
  var StatuslistArray = Write(Stringlists);
</script>
```

Also you can use ID of the list to retrieve the information using SSJS.

**Reference:**

- [List Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listRetrieve.htm)
- [Server Side Javascript (SSJS)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm)